# Android. ViewPager ест всю память

Tags: android-fragment, android-viewpager, android, java, утечка-памяти

Здраствуй сообщество.

У меня есть 3 фрагмента и ViewPager. но есть маленькая проблема: ети три фрагмента должны идти по кругу, то есть 1-2-3-1 и т.д. Я это сделал, но теперь есть проблема с памятью, некоторые элементы у меня `static` например `Adapter` для вывода списков, что бы их можно `notifyDataSetChanged()` из другого фрагмента.
Но из-за этого, когда идет свайп в сторону, предыдущий фрагмент `Fragment1` удаляется, а новий `Fragment1` создается, из-за того что фрагменты пересоздаются - память забивается. и я не могу найти в чем проблема.
Как можно пофиксить или как сделать `circle swap` 3 фрагментов что бы не пересоздавать их, а подставлять уже существующие в памяти

Comment: Не понимаю, а в чём проблема не создавать каждый раз новый фрагмент в адаптере, а возвращать уже существующий?

Comment: Та так и хотелось, но как ? есть где-то пример, а то что-то нормальное немогу придумать.
"android:switcher:" + context.pager.getId() + ":" + position; пробивал достучатся и в фрагменте витаскивать по тегу, нифга - ошибка, что-то типа не тот фрагмент

Comment: Например, сохранять фрагмент в коллекции в адаптере, при вызове `instantiateItem` (не забывая, разумеется, удалять его оттуда в `destroyItem`). В `getItem` же смотрите, есть ли для этой позиции уже созданный фрагмент, и либо возвращаете его, либо создаёте новый.